# D lang enum with basetype surprising behaviour

Tags: enums, d

I am dabbling in D, and was surprised at the behavior of named vs anonymous enums with a specified base-type. Given the following D code:

```d
import std.stdio;

enum strs : string 
{
    Foo = "Hello", 
    Bar = "World",
}

enum : string 
{
    anon1 = "pen", 
    anon2 = "sword",
}

int main(string[] args)
{
    writefln("%s %s", strs.Foo, strs.Bar);
    writefln("%s %s", anon1, anon2);

    return 0;
}
```

This outputs:

```
Foo Bar
pen sword
```

So in other words, for a named enum, passing a value to writefln as string prints the name of the value, not the value itself. But for an anonymous enum, doing the same thing does print the value itself.

This seems like a strange inconsistency. So why is this?

I am using Visual D 0.3.42.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, part of the problem is that the keyword `enum` is arguably overused in D. An anonymous enum is sometimes called a manifest constant. Declaring

```d
enum : string 
{
    anon1 = "pen", 
    anon2 = "sword",
}
```

is basically the same as

```d
enum string anon1 = "pen";
enum string anon2 = "sword";
```

or

```d
enum anon1 = "pen";
enum anon2 = "sword";
```

since they'll be inferred as `string` anyway. These really aren't enums. It's just that you declared them in a block rather than separately. They're more like #defining a constant in C in that you're declaring a symbol that has no address and will simply be replaced with the value it was assigned wherever that symbol is used. It isn't a list of associated values like an `enum` is typically supposed to be. In fact, these assertions will fail:

```d
assert(is(typeof(anon1) == enum));
assert(is(typeof(anon2) == enum));
```

And that's because they're manifest constants and not really enums in the traditional sense. Contrast that with

```d
assert(is(typeof(strs.Foo) == enum));
assert(is(typeof(strs.Bar) == enum));
```

which will pass - because `strs` is an actual `enum` rather than a manifest constant (though enums are similar to manifest constants in that they have no address, and when you use them, they just get replaced with their value - which might be part of why manifest constants also use the `enum` keyword).

So, from `writefln`'s perspective, `anon1`, and `anon2` are just strings, and it'll print them like any string, whereas `Foo` and `Bar` are enums, and so it'll print their names. Internally, `writefln` is using `is(T == enum)` to check whether something is an `enum`, and just like with those assertions, only the ones which are actual enums rather than manifest constants will result in that expression being true, so they're the ones that get their names printed.

Answer (score 3):

Nameless enums are simply a block of manifest constants, and do not have their own type. Meaning:

```d
enum : string 
{
    anon1 = "pen", 
    anon2 = "sword",
}
```

...is the same as...

```d
enum string anon1 = "pen";
enum string anon2 = "sword";
```

However, your `strs` enum is a type of its own, so `writefln` prints out the enum field names (however strange that may be).